Spring Boot ThymeLeaf form date input
I'm using Spring Boot with ThymeLeaf and cannot obtain proper date format in form.
I can format dates for output in HTML elements like . Saving date from user input also works. But sending date to form for user update doesn't work as date is not properly formated. Date appears in <input ...> tag with proper data but wrong format.
<input id="birthDate" type="date" name="birthDate" value="20/06/1966">
Date is formated dd/MM/yyyy was HTML form expects yyyy/MM/dd.
Entity class:
public class Patient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate birthDate;

    // default parameterless constructor required for Entity creation
    protected Patient() {
    }
    
    // All value constructor
    public Patient(Long i, String ln, String fn, LocalDate bd) {
        id = i;
        lastName = ln;
        firstName = fn;
        birthDate = bd;
    }
    
    // All value constructor
    public Patient(String ln, String fn, LocalDate bd) {
        lastName = ln;
        firstName = fn;
        birthDate = bd;
    }
}

Service class:
@Service
public class PatientService {
    private final PatientRepository repository;

    public PatientService(PatientRepository rep) {
        repository = rep;
    }

    public Patient createPatient(PatientCreationParameters parameters) {
        Patient user = new Patient(parameters.getLastName(), parameters.getFirstName(), parameters.getBirthdate());
        return repository.save(user);
    }

    public Patient updatePatient(Long id, PatientCreationParameters parameters) {
        Patient Patient = new Patient(id, parameters.getLastName(), parameters.getFirstName(), parameters.getBirthdate());
        return repository.save(Patient);
    }
    
    public Patient getPatient(Long id) {
        return repository.getReferenceById(id);
    }

    public List<Patient> getPatients() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }
}

HTML template:
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Patients</title>
</head>
<body>
<main>
    <h1>Create patient</h1>
    <form th:object="${formData}" th:action="${add} ? @{/patients/create} : @{/patients/{id}/edit}" method="post">
        <div>
            <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
            <input id="lastName" type="text" th:field="*{lastName}">
            <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('lastName')}" th:text="${#strings.listJoin(#fields.errors('lastName'), ', ')}"></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="firstName">First name</label>
            <input id="firstName" type="text" th:field="*{firstName}">
            <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}" th:text="${#strings.listJoin(#fields.errors('firstName'), ', ')}"></p>
        </div>
        <div>
           <label for="birthDate">Birth date</label>
           <input id="birthDate" type="date" th:field="*{birthDate}">
           <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('birthDate')}" th:text="${#strings.listJoin(#fields.errors('birthDate'), ', ')}"></p>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Create patient</button>
    </form>
</main>
</body>
</html>


For now, using a "dirty" workaround by setting the value during onLoad with the javascript:
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
   window.onload = function () { 
      document.getElementById("birthDate").value = [[${#temporals.format(formData.birthDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}]];
   }
</script>

As setting value with formated date does not provide field value with proper formated date.
